# csrf token doesn't match in form re-submission through browser's refresh button

Tags: php, csrf, page-refresh

I have a csrf token that I send within a form and also store it in the session so I can verify if they are equal when the form is submitted.

The csrf token is generated on every page load, which means the csrf token in the session is changing as well. however when I re-submit the form with the browser "refresh" button, it sends the old token which throw an error..

Is there a way to change the token in the cached browser data ?

Comment: Surely you don't want resubmission on every refresh, that's part of the point of CSRF? If someone submits a form once, and then refreshes the form receiving page, that will resubmit anew on every refresh.... spam

Comment: @medBouzid did you ever get the tokens to match properly?

Comment: @kejo I don't really remember... I'm even surprised that  asked this question 5 years ago! wow time goes fast

Answer (score 1):

No. It isn't even cached data, you're asking the browser to repeat the previous request.

You might be able to avoid the problem by using the [PGR pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) so that the refresh just loads a display page and doesn't resubmit the form data for processing.

That said, it is generally considered fine to [generate the token once per session](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Synchronizer_.28CSRF.29_Tokens) rather than on every page load. This would also solve problems with people accessing the site in two tabs at once.

Comment: I was using rails for all my previous web development apps and I can see the csrf token changing within the form every refresh, and even it's allowed to re-submit the data on refresh, so I am confused here ?!

Comment: @medBo maybe the token is a password hash of a fixed value held in session. Therefore the hash always changes each time the password is generated but it always compares correctly to the session value.